# Product prices always round up

Tags: magento2.2

I'm using a minimal modified Magento CE 2.2.7 with a free Solwin template, nothing fancy.

When I add products, Magento automatically rounds up the prices. 
eg:

- €2.30 becomes €2
- €2.60 becomes €3

I understand this is a feature, one that should not be active by default.
It however is enabled by default. I have tried several plugins that are made for manipulating the rounding mechanism, which also gives me the option to disable rounding (https://packagist.org/packages/faonni/module-price for example) but these don't seem to have any effect, the problem persists.

The exact same problem is described here, but no logic answer has been provided: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12210
"Found the issue was due to the precision being automatically set to 2 and bootstrap.php being ignored changed it on server level to 14 and issue resolved" is not something I can translate in to specific actions.

Can anybody point me in the right direction? Everything else seem to work just fine and we are getting to production state, so reinstalling isn't really an option at this point.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rounding seems to be an undocumented feature of the custom template being used.